# Generating synthethic default imports

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am using WebPack with `awesome-typescript-loader`. I am trying to migrate to module type "es2015", so I had to replace all `import ... = require('...');` constructs with `import ... from '...'` and enabled option of TypeScript compiler `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`. It compiles fine, but at runtime I am getting `undefined` from those imported modules. If I understand it correctly `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` only tells TypeScript compiler how to type check, not how to emit code.

So my question is:
**How to set it up** (WebPack [e.g. add some loader] or awesome-typescript-loader) **to actually generate those default imports so at runtime I am getting correct values?**